# How to pass image data to a parent app in Android with Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-intent

I built an image viewer app that I also want to use as a file picker, but I can't bring it to actually send the image data to the parent app.

I couldn't find any documentation related to my specific problem. I read about invoke methods, intents and activities, but what I tried didn't work at all. I'd like to have a simple function like `passToParent(imagePath)` that does exactly that.

To illustrate exactly what I'm trying to do: In any app, e.g. my web browser I click something like 'Open Image' which opens my stock file picker that lets me open other apps such as my image viewer. There I can select my image. What I then want to happen, is my app and the file picker to close and the selected image to be uploaded.

Comment: `can't bring it to actually send the image data to the parent app.` You do that in the same way as when your activity was started with startActivityForResult().

Comment: Apparently I can't do that from a Flutter app? All I did to make my app callable from other apps was to add an intent filter to the main activity in the AndroidManifest.xml with action.GET_CONTENT, category.DEFAULT, category.OPENABLE and mimeType="image/*".  I'm not sure what format is expected of the file either (A Uint8List?) or how to write the function exactly.